# why 2 different coordinates for SF in d3.js test suite?

Tags: d3.js

The d3.js geo projection test suite uses some well know locations as test data. However the latitude/longitude for the same location can vary by test.

Why?

Thanks

```
~/workspace/d3/test/geo$ grep -r "San Francisco" *
albers-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[-122.42000000,   37.78000000], [ 107.44485839,  214.04820561]],
albers-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[-122.42000000,   37.78000000], [  -0.34818238,   -0.03359981]],
albers-usa-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[-122.42000000,   37.78000000], [ 107.44485839,  214.04820561]],
albers-usa-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[-122.42000000,   37.78000000], [  -0.34818238,   -0.03359981]],
azimuthal-equal-area-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 448.09318291,   57.65281089]],
azimuthal-equal-area-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.21271211,   -1.28231459]],
azimuthal-equidistant-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 445.26741926,   40.61796552]],
azimuthal-equidistant-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.23155054,   -1.39588023]],
conic-conformal-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 442.69098342,   47.64115003]],
conic-conformal-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.24872678,   -1.34905900]],
conic-equal-area-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 433.22520615,   32.16847746]],
conic-equal-area-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.31183196,   -1.45221015]],
conic-equidistant-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 437.79988730,   40.06576540]],
conic-equidistant-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.28133408,   -1.39956156]],
equirectangular-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 359.13715001,   48.28497214]],
equirectangular-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.80575233,   -1.34476685]],
gnomonic-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 323.76600022, -691.84169545]],
gnomonic-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -1.04156000,   -6.27894464]],
mercator-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 359.13715001,  -76.39503103]],
mercator-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620841,   77.04946502], [  -0.80575234,   -2.17596687]],
orthographic-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 455.75069916,  103.81541376]],
orthographic-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.16166201,   -0.97456391]],
stereographic-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 459.00877672,  123.45642208]],
stereographic-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.13994149,   -0.84362385]],
transverse-mercator-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [ 455.53607488,   38.07095444]],
transverse-mercator-test.js:      "San Francisco, CA": [[ -46.16620803,   77.04946507], [  -0.16309283,   -1.41286030]],
~/workspace/d3/test/geo$
```

Comment: Looks like the data may be incorrect. Does it matter?

Comment: "Does it matter?" Possibly not. These are projection tests, so it could mean that the projections are wrong... or it could mean that the test _labels_ are wrong, which would not matter.

I'm having some trouble with projections and I thought I might be missing something simple...like I'm using the wrong units or I have my lat/lon values swapped.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of what you're having trouble with?

Comment: I'm trying to scale and position maps, which I asked about (and you provided a helpful suggestion) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271987/how-to-position-small-geographies-in-viewport-using-d3. I saw the Bostock process of using the path bounding box with a center of 0,0 and a scale of 1 in order to calculate new values for scale and translate. I tried this with 2 points in SF but the answer didn't look right so I asked about that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275175/explain-d3js-projection-fundamentals. I continue to dig and noticed the discrepancies in the d3 test code.

Comment: It certainly looks like the two different sets of coordinates are wrong. You could open [an issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues?state=open) about this.