# how to create map from given coordinates in d3js

Tags: d3.js

So I need to create the map of my country from the coordinates I have so that I can plot some xyz data on it.
I was able to plot the map with the help of Mike Bostock tut http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/
But when I went through the .json file, the coordinates mentioned are totally different from the coordinates I have. Like Patna(India) has [5812,6567] as coordinates in the json file while actual coordinates are [25,85].

Could anybody guide me how can I use the coordinates with me to plot the map and then display some data on it??

EDIT:
With the help from @user1614080, I was able to understand how coordinates are converted into screen coordinates.
The issue I have is: I want the map of India in a certain way. For that purpose, I would like to use the list of latitude & longitude I have. But I dont know how to convert these lat-longs into topojson/geojson format.

For the time being I did a simple line plot with the lat-long I had. Some of the values from the coordinates.csv I used for the line plot are:

Longitude,Latitude
88.75,21.58
88.33,21.50
88.17,22.08
88.00,21.75
87.58,21.58
87.08,21.42

But I would like to use topojson/geojson for the same. how can I convert the data from "coordinates.csv" into json?

Comment: a look at your JSON file may help ?

Comment: I haven't created a JSON file as of now, I just have the coordinates... Since looking into the JSON file used by Mike Bostock didn't help, so I wish to know how exactly the JSON file should be in order to plot the map and superimpose some data on it....

Comment: You need to pass your coordinates to the `projection` function so it can calculate the screen coordinates.  The coordinates that you have quoted `[25,85]` could be the screen coordinates or a topojson conversion.  With out some working code it is difficult to help further.  Although [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275175/explain-d3js-projection-fundamentals?noredirect=1#comment30303287_20275175) might help.